# Calculate $\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\frac{|\sin x-\cos x|}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, solution-verification, closed-form

How to prove that

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\frac{|\sin x-\cos x|}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\ dx=\frac{2^{\frac74}e^{\frac{\large-\pi}{8}}}{1-e^{-\pi}}$$

This problem is [proposed](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3638742206166927&set=gm.662656357830868&type=3&theater&ifg=1) by a friend and no solution has been submitted yet.

The proposer gives a hint "Calculate the integral on D where D is the set of all values in the domain $(0, +\infty)$ where the integrand is defined."

There was some arguing over the closed form  as some claims that it should involve an imaginary part.

I do not know how to start but I tried to determine the domain of the integrand and I could not.

My question is the closed form right? and if so, how to prove it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume that the integral to be computed is
$$I=\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\frac{|\sin x-\cos x|}{\sqrt{\color{red}|\sin x\color{red}|}}\ dx.$$

Obviously:
$$
I=\frac1{1-e^{-\pi/2}}\int_0^\pi e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\frac{|\sin x-\cos x|}{\sqrt{|\sin x|}}\ dx
$$
as the function $\frac{|\sin x-\cos x|}{\sqrt{|\sin x|}}$ is $\pi$-periodic.

Now:
$$
\int_0^\pi e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\frac{|\sin x-\cos x|}{\sqrt{|\sin x|}}dx=
\int_0^{\pi/4} e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}dx
+\int_{\pi/4}^\pi e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}dx\\
=2\left[e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\sqrt{\sin x}\right]_0^{\pi/4}
-2\left[e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\sqrt{\sin x}\right]_{\pi/4}^{\pi}=e^{-\pi/8}2^{7/4},
$$
where we used:
$$\int e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}dx
=2\int e^{-\frac{x}{2}}d\sqrt{\sin x}-\int e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}dx\\
=2 e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\sqrt{\sin x}+\int e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\sqrt{\sin x}dx-\int e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}dx\\
=2e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\sqrt{\sin x}.
$$

Comment: Impressive +1.  So that might be the right question. So I think the closed form I gave is missing 1/2 for the exponent of e in the denominator?

Comment: @AliShather Yes, the factor seems to be missed (as well as the absolute value of the sine in the denominator).

Answer (score 0):

Solution by Khalef Ruhemi ( He is not an MSE user)

Considering only the real part, the integrand is defined for $2n\pi<x<(2n+1)\pi,\quad n=0,1,2...$ , so

$$I=\Re\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\frac{|\sin x-\cos x|}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\ dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{2\pi n}^{(2n+1)\pi}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\frac{|\sin x-\cos x|}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\ dx$$

set $y=x-2\pi n$ we get

$$I=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\pi n}\int_0^\pi e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\frac{|\sin x-\cos x|}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\ dx$$

where

$$\int_0^\pi e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\frac{|\sin x-\cos x|}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\ dx=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\ dx+\int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\pi e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\ dx$$

By integration by parts we have

$$\int e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\ dx=2e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\sqrt{\sin x}$$

$$\Longrightarrow \int_0^\pi e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\frac{|\sin x-\cos x|}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\ dx=2^{\frac74}e^{-\frac{\pi}{8}}$$

$$\Longrightarrow I=2^{\frac74}e^{-\frac{\pi}{8}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\pi n}=\frac{2^{\frac74}e^{\frac{\large-\pi}{8}}}{1-e^{-\pi}}$$

Comment: Essentially it is the same solution as mine except for a decision to ignore one half of the integration domain.

Comment: @user He solved it at the same time you did . You can see his solution on the link I provided in the question. No the integrand is different he didnt take the absolute value for  the sin under the square root.

Comment: The integrand in his case is not real, but he just ignores all the parts of the integration domain where it is imaginary. The reason for this is unclear as the computation of the imaginary integral is equally simple.

Comment: Just multiply the result by $(1-i e^{-\pi/2})$, where $i=\sqrt{-1}$.